# How should the client encode a websocket message before sending to server?

Tags: java, websocket

Does anyone know how to implement the method below:

```
public void encode(ByteBuffer rawMessage, ByteBuffer messageReadyToBeSentToServer);
```

Let's say I want to send "Hello World!" to the websocket server. How do I encode according to the *simple* websocket protocol spec below:

```
0                   1                   2                   3
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
 +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
 |F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
 |I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
 |N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
 | |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
 +-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 |     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
 + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
 |                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
 +-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
 | Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
 +-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 :                     Payload Data continued ...                :
 + - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
 |                     Payload Data continued ...                |
 +---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the implementation of `write(WebSocketFrame)` method of `WebSocketOutputStream` class in **[nv-websocket-client](https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client)** (WebSocket client library in Java).